# Universal Image Loader for Android with ImageView in Fragment

Tags: java, android, universal-image-loader

I am using UIL for loading and displaying images in a ListFragment wich works great.
In the ListView I am using the Handler-Pattern. No problem so far.

But if I click on a ListEntry to display another image within a second fragment it fails.

The weird thing is if I click on a button in the second fragment do load that image, it works like a charme.

The log-output shows in both cases that the image is in the disc-cache, that it was scaled aso. - no errors.

This function is part of the Fragment: (and is always called from Thread 1 (UI))

```
    public void updateStockInfo(final String symbol) {

    if (viewer != null) {
        //final ImageView imageview = (ImageView) viewer.findViewById(R.id.stockinfo);

        urlForStockInfo = "http://chart.finance.yahoo.com/c/3m/d/" + symbol.toLowerCase();

        imageloader.loadImage(getActivity(), urlForStockInfo, new ImageLoadingListener() {
            ...

            @Override
            public void onLoadingComplete(final Bitmap loadedImage) {
                imageview.setImageBitmap(loadedImage);
                logger.debug("Loadinf complete");
            }
        });
    }
```

Calling updateStockInfo from onActivityCreated (its the same with onCreateView) fails without an exception or so. 
The thread for loading the image does not start.
In LoadAndDisplayImageTas:run() there is a check for Thread.interrupted() on line 89 - this check fails.

Buuuuuttt if manually (press button) call updateStockInfo if works???

In all cases updateStockInfo is called by the UI-Thread.

Any hints?
thx in advance!

[**Update**]
I downloaded the source and removed the check for Thread.interupted() on line 92

```
        if (/* Thread.interrupted() || */checkTaskIsNotActual()) return;
    if (configuration.loggingEnabled) Log.i(ImageLoader.TAG, String.format(LOG_DISPLAY_IMAGE_IN_IMAGEVIEW, imageLoadingInfo.memoryCacheKey));
```

You know what - it works.
Was this a bug or does it just work for my special case?

Comment: Do you call imageLoader.stop() somewhere? And why do you use ```loadImage(...)``` but not ```displayImage(...)```?

Comment: No, there is no .stop(). That was my first thought. I commet them out. I used displayImage before - the same result.

Comment: SORRY! I thought I commented them all out but I missed one in the first Activity! Thanks for your help and sorry for bothering you. 

AND! Thanks for the great library!

Comment: Ok, I'll create the answer for this question so it can be marked as "answered".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More likely you call `ImageLoader.stop()` somewhere in activity.